# Form integration on Sage Pay

Tags: php, html, magento

I've been asked to create a very simple HTML form which then integrates into Sage Pay using Form integration. All I've been asked to put on the HTML form is 'booking ref' and 'total amount to pay' which the customer enters manually, along with the other mandatory details Sage Pay requires to successfully process payment.

I've spoken to Sage Pay and they've advised I use a shopping cart like Magento but I think this is too intense for their needs as the website is not an e-commerce site.

Is it possible to create a simple form and then integrate this into Sage Pay without using a shopping cart, or can anyone recommend a very simple shopping cart which will allow me to edit it so the user doesn't have to select products and can enter free text details as above?

Comment: There should be an example on the Sage Page site, I'd guess? Maybe this: http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/find-an-integration-document/form-integration

Comment: Thanks. I did install this but it showed a basket with list of products to choose from. Tried to edit this to just free form text boxes, but its far too complicated for me to figure out how to amend the backend scripts to integrate. My php scripting knowledge is basic which is why Sage Pay recommended using shopping carts instead as most of the scripting is already done for you. However the ones I've seen look too intense for what I require! Thank you though

Comment: It looks like [you only need a form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738929/sagepay-form-integration-error-3045), and SP does the rest. I've never used Sage, mind you.